# can I bind a richtextbox text property to list or array in winforms

Tags: winforms, data-binding, binding, richtextbox

I am looking to bind a richtextbox's text property to an array or list of custom objects. Is this possible? I see lots of WPF related binding for richtextbox but I am doing this in winforms. My searches for an example article have not turned up anything of value yet. Figured I would ask here.

One of my database calls returns to me a list of specific instructions and I would like to stuff this entire list of instructions into the richtextbox all at once. The text property does not support an IEnumerable type so I am not sure if I can do what I am trying to do or not. I was looking for a method to fill my richtextbox without all the for looping and inserting one item at a time. I figured data binding was the best fit for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've run across the same problem and have solved it by creating a custom ValueConverter. The code for it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/3905438).

Basically it takes an IEnumerable in and then returns a string with a custom separator (defaults to NewLine).